# Plone 4 dexterity viewform - add css Class to widget in fieldset X

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I have a dexterity based content type with different edit views and fieldsets defined in the schema. Whenever I want to update a widget/field in another than the first fieldset, it gets crumpy. For example:

```
self.groups[0].fields['my_field'].mode = HIDDEN_MODE
```

must be used to hide `my_field` from the **2nd** fieldset. To make the same field required

```
self.schema['my_field'].required = True
```

does the trick.

But how can I add a css class to a widget on another than the first fieldset? I mean, what

```
self.fields['my_field_on_first_fieldset'].widget.addClass("myClass")
```

would do, if my widget would be on the first fieldset "page".

Comment: What happens, when you apply the suggested line?

Comment: Which "suggested" line?

Comment: The last one. You are asking what it would do, I was wondering why you don't just try and see...

Comment: Maybe I was unclear here. I know, what the line does, but I am looking for the loc that does add a class on a different than the first fieldset. See title.

Comment: Could you clarify your quest, then? Frankly. to me it's a confusing mix of topics (hidden-mode, set-required and add-class). You could f.e. post a line, which you expect to work and tell us what happens instead. Just a suggestion :-)

Comment: Please read the question. I made quite clear, what I need to know.

Comment: It would have been helpful to have the relevant parts of the actual, concrete code your using, to tell what you've tried and what happened. Refs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Martin Aspeli's tutorial](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/widgets-1), I tested your request and can confirm that oddly the 
klass-attribute cannot be applied on invisible widgets in the sub-fieldsets, returning a 'Key Error' in reference to the widget's name.

With other attributes, f.e. 'size', there is no problem.

Instead you can apply the class via Javascript.

If you want to provide a fallback in case the client hasn't Javascript enabled, you can add a condition in updateWidget(), checking if it is enabled and if not, apply the class with addClass() respectively the klass-attribute. Which will work then, because all fields are shown and not hidden anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I surfed around this by changing the form id by defining an id property for all my sub-forms, so that I could conditionally style my forms. But thanks for the investigation. Never intended to confuse one.

Comment: No prob, glad you found a solution :) If you feel motivated, you could  file a report at z3c.form's repo on github... Best, i.