# How to customize z3c.form widget for fields inside groups (fieldsets)

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I have a Plone custom control panel registry and I'm trying to use a well know method to customize some of the widgets properties for `zope.schema.Text` and `zope.schema.TextField`.

I commonly customize the `updateWidgets` in that way:

```python
def updateWidgets(self):
    super(MyEditForm, self).updateWidgets()
    self.widgets['my_text_area'].style = 'width: 100%'
    self.widgets['my_text_area'].rows = 7
```

But now I'm working on a form where fields are splitted in two fieldsets:

```python
class MySettingsEditForm(controlpanel.RegistryEditForm):
    schema = IMySettingsSchema
    groups = (Form1, Form2)
    # fields = nothing
```

If I try to access `self.widgets['my_text_area']` I get `KeyError`. It seems that as I did't defined the `fields` attribute I can't access directly widgets.

I found that I have `groups` so I can call something like `self.groups[0].fields['my_text_area']` but still I find no way to access widgets for fields inside groups.

How can I customize widgets attributes when using groups?

Comment: Cannot find the sources quickly, but I think to remember, that it is not possible :-(

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/issues/2

Comment: Thanks @IdaEbkes! Reading at the issue and related SO question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385575/plone-4-dexterity-viewform-add-css-class-to-widget-in-fieldset-x it talks about hidden field. I have problems with *visible* fields, so I fear I missed something during debug.
Stay tuned...

Comment: Yes, it's more a resemblence. I remember to have had another issue with updating/manipulating dex-fieldsets... Curious, if someone goes for the bounty, surely I'll stay tuned!  `this.addEventListener()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is playing with widget subform, see this code:

```
def fix_table_widget(self, name, widgets):
    sub_widgets = widgets[name].widgets
    for widget in sub_widgets:
        new_label = widget.subform.widgets['weekday'].value
        widget.subform.widgets['selected'].items[0]['label'] = new_label
        widget.subform.widgets['weekday'].mode = 'hidden'

def schoolrequest_customizations(self):
    ''' Customizations for the schoolrequest base views
    '''
    for group in self.groups:
        widgets = group.widgets
        if 'table_bus_to_school' in widgets:
            self.block_widget_table('table_bus_to_school', widgets)
            self.fix_table_widget('table_bus_to_school', widgets)

        if 'table_bus_to_home' in widgets:
            self.block_widget_table('table_bus_to_home', widgets)
            self.fix_table_widget('table_bus_to_home', widgets)

def update(self):
    super(MyForm, self).update()
    self.schoolrequest_customizations()
```

Comment: Is not working, I get `AttributeError: 'GroupFactory' object has no attribute 'widgets'` when accessing `group.widgets`

Comment: Oh I see. I was launching that code in the update method and not in the updateWidgets.